# Bootstrap - How to use equal widths in a navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap in Django/Python. I am having trouble using equal widths in a navbar.

I've set up the collapse configuration in my menu. But I can't seem to apply equal widths to its items before collapsing. I want the menu items to be equal width and in the center of the page, but instead they are on the left side.

How can I solve it?

#### HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav text-center" aria-expanded>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the bootstrap grid system, (seen here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) You could give each of your list elements the class col-10 and offset-1. This will make them all the same width and also center them slightly in the middle of the page.

If you want them to be smaller you could also give them col-6 and an offset of 3 for example.

if you want them to be full width simply give them the col-12 class or evenly spaced with just col.

You can also make them different sizes based upon breakpoints/window res with classes like col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 (full width on mobile and then less wide but centered on larger displays.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for responsive behavior,

```css
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%; /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>

<h2>Responsive Navbar with Links of Same Width</h2>
<p>Try to resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>

<div class="navbar">
<a class="active" href="#">Home</a> 
<a href="#">Search</a> 
<a href="#">Contact</a> 
<a href="#">Login</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```